# How can I solve the problem in mixstock packages?

Tags: r, function, package

I am trying to run mixstock packages. but i got some problem adapting my data.

this is process of roading my data

> test<-read.csv("real5.csv")
> test<-as.mixstock.data(test,nmix=2)
> test<-markfreq.condense(test)
> test
> [image]

this is many to many process code provided by Bolker using mixstock packages.

> Zfit0 = mm.wbugs(test,returntype="bugs",pkg = "JAGS",bugs.code = "BB",n.iter = 300)
> but herein i got error messeage.
> [image]

i want to use bugs.code="BB" but i cant use this(when i use "TO" instead of "BB" in bugs.code it works. but i want to know why got error when using bugs.code="BB" in my data) could this problem be solved?

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks in advance!

If you request the files and information necessary to solve the problem, I will send you the relevant files and information. thank you!